# how to use javascript function in a form button?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know anything about html and most especially javascript.. but we have this activity on how you'll call the javascript function that is located at the `<head></head>` of the html tag?

And what if there are several functions? Can I call it at the same time in one button? or should I create another function and put all the functions in there?

This is what our activity is all about... in a javascript button, when clicked, it must calculate all transactions? I have 5 functions, and one of them is called by a button tag, while the other 4 are inside of that function. I don't really know what to do... But when I clicked the button, nothing will happen. Btw, it's a Reservation form, so when the button is clicked, it must calculate all the inputs and shows a confirmation page/alert with the prices and such. Thanks guys!

This is my code of the form:

```
<form name="reserve" action="" id="reserve" method="post">

<fieldset>
<legend>Contact Information</legend>
<label for="name">Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="firstname" 
  onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';"
  onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="lastname"
  onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" 
  onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
<br>

<label for="address">Address: </label>
<textarea name="address" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>

<br>

<label for="city">City: </label>
<input type="text" name="city">

<label for="country">Country: </label>
<select name="country">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="PH">Philippines</option>
<option value="TH">Thailand</option>
<option value="VN">Vietnam</option>
<option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
<option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
<option value="SG">Singapore</option>
</select>

<br>

<label for="email">Email: </label>
<input type="email" name="email">

<label for="phone">Phone: </label>
<input type="tel" name="phone">
</fieldset>
<hr>

<fieldset>
<legend>Accomodation Request</legend>
<label for="checkin">Check-in: </label>
<input type="date" name="checkin">

<label for="checkout">Check-out: </label>
<input type="date" name="checkout">

<br>

<label for="roomtype">Room type: </label> <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="s" name="roomtype" value="superior">Superior  |||||
<label for="sguest">No.of guests: </label>
<input type="text" id="supg" name="sguest" size="3"> <br>

<input type="checkbox" id="d" name="roomtype" value=deluxe">Deluxe |||||||
<label for="dguest">No.of guests: </label>
<input type="text" id="delg" name="dguest" size="3"> <br> 

<input type="checkbox" id="p" name="roomtype" value="Premier">Premier |||||
<label for="pguest">No.of guests: </label>
<input type="text" id="premg" name="pguest" size="3"> <br>
</fieldset>

<br>
<hr>

<label for="adinfo">Additional Information:</label>
<textarea name="adinfo" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
<br><br>
<hr>
<input type="button" name="submit" onclick="formSubmit()" 
  class="submit" value="Reserve">



</form>
```

And this is javascript code:

```
function superiorroom(){
    var roomprice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["reserve"]
    var s = theForm.elements["s"]
    var supg = theForm.elements["supg"]
    var t=0;

    If (s.checked==true)
    {
        roomprice=5400;
        squantity=parseInt(squantity.value);
        t=parseInt(t);
        t= (roomprice*squantity)*supg;
    }
    return t;
}

function deluxeroom(){
    var roomprice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["reserve"]
    var d = theForm.elements["d"]
    var delg = theForm.elements["delg"]
    var u=0;

    If (d.checked==true)
    {
        roomprice=7200;
        dquantity=parseInt(dquantity.value);
        u=parseInt(u);
        u= (roomprice*dquantity)*delg;
    }
    return u;
}

function premiumroom(){
    var roomprice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["reserve"]
    var p = theForm.elements["p"]
    var premg = theForm.elements["premg"]
    var v=0;

    If (p.checked==true)
    {
        roomprice=9800;
        pquantity=parseInt(pquantity.value);
        v=parseInt(v);
        v= (roomprice*pquantity)*premg;
    }
    return u;
}


</script>
```

I hope you can help me guys!

Comment: Where's the `formSubmit()` function??

Comment: oh sorry... inside the forumsubmit() function are the 4 other functions(totalp(), superiorroom() and others.)

Comment: Can you show me that function? I think it's necessary to analyze what's wrong here.

Comment: don't put the java script code on your events , write everything in a java script function and call the function on the event .

Comment: <input type="text" name="lastname" value="lastname" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" 

onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>  Instead of all this mess, why not just use placeholders? ex: <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name"> This is HTML5

Comment: can you show me how to do that?? in Visual Basic?

Comment: Do you want to use `<button>` or `<input type=submit>`? 1st clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have change your code a little check it

```
<input type="button" name="submit" onclick="return formSubmit()" class="submit" value="Reserve">
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code as like this : Try This
Button

```
<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="return formSubmit()" class="submit" value="Reserve">
```

`Scripts`

```
<script>
$("#submit").click(function () {
       if ( document.getElementById("s").checked =checked)
           superiorroom();
        else if(document.getElementById("d").checked =checked)
            deluxeroom();
        else if(document.getElementById("p").checked =checked)
           premiumroom();

    });
</script>

<script>
function superiorroom(){
    var roomprice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["reserve"]
    var s = theForm.elements["s"]
    var supg = theForm.elements["supg"]
    var t=0;

    If (s.checked==true)
    {
        roomprice=5400;
        squantity=parseInt(squantity.value);
        t=parseInt(t);
        t= (roomprice*squantity)*supg;
    }
    return t;
}

function deluxeroom(){
    var roomprice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["reserve"]
    var d = theForm.elements["d"]
    var delg = theForm.elements["delg"]
    var u=0;

    If (d.checked==true)
    {
        roomprice=7200;
        dquantity=parseInt(dquantity.value);
        u=parseInt(u);
        u= (roomprice*dquantity)*delg;
    }
    return u;
}

function premiumroom(){
    var roomprice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["reserve"]
    var p = theForm.elements["p"]
    var premg = theForm.elements["premg"]
    var v=0;

    If (p.checked==true)
    {
        roomprice=9800;
        pquantity=parseInt(pquantity.value);
        v=parseInt(v);
        v= (roomprice*pquantity)*premg;
    }
    return u;
}
</script>
```